# How to fix error "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No video id found: [object Object]"

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm tried to create a simple music bot for discord using `ytdl-core`, but my development stopped at moment when console show me error **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No video id found: [object Object]**, i don't know how to fix it, here is all my music code part

```
        let song = args, voice = message.member.voice.channel
        let connection = voice.join()
        if (!song) {
            message.react("❌")
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor("Error!")
                .addField("Input URL adress of music")
                .setColor(embedRed)
            message.channel.send(embed)
            return
        }
        if (!voice) {
            message.react("❌")
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor("Error!")
                .addField("Join voice channel!")
                .setColor(embedRed)
            message.channel.send(embed)
        }
        let valid = ytdl.validateURL(song)
        if (!valid) {
            message.react("❌")
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor("Error!")
            .addField("Your URL adress is not valid")
            .setColor(embedRed)
        message.channel.send(embed)
        }
        let guild_queue = queue.get(message.guild.id)
        if (!guild_queue) guild_queue = queue.set(message.guild.id, {songs: []}).get(message.guild.id)

        guild_queue.songs.push(song)
        message.react("✅")
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor("Music")
            .addField("Track added to queue")
            .setColor(embedGreen)
        message.channel.send(embed)
        if (guild_queue.songs.length < 2) play(connection, guild_queue.songs)  
    }
    async function play(connection, songs) {
        let music = await ytdl(songs[0], {filter: 'audioonly'})
        console.log(songs)
        connection.play(ytdl(`${music}`, { quality: 'highestaudio' }));
```

i'm not profesional coder, it's just my hobby

yea, it's my first question :)

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace of the error, in order to know in which lines it is failing.

Comment: all what i find in error

**at play (E:\DiscordBots\Node Js\MyBOt\bot.js:213:25)**

213 line is 
```connection.play(ytdl(`${music}`, { quality: 'highestaudio' }));```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ytdl` returns a [readable stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable), not a `Promise`, so there's no need to use `await`. You were then passing the stringified `music` stream (`'[object Object]'`) into `ytdl`, which `ytdl` obviously can't get a video ID out of.

Try this:

```js
async function play(connection, songs) {
  const music = ytdl(songs[0], {filter: 'audioonly', quality: 'highestaudio'})
  connection.play(music)
}
```

Comment: it's was useful, but i have a new error, im trying to fix it